# Universal Analytics Google - Custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics

What's the difference between

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  'data goes here'
});
```

and

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'data goes here');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Doesn't it accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

If you limit the answer the way you framed your question there is no difference at all.

The difference is that when you use `set` that custom dimension will be sent with every hit in the current page. Here's a better example:

1) In this example the pageview has the custom dimension attached but the event does not.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  'data goes here'
});
ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Action');
```

2) In this second example both the pageview and the event have the custom dimension attached.

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'data goes here');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Action');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I have the following 2 lines will I get 2 hits for each page load, therefore showing incorrect data in Google Analytics?
ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1': 'data goes here' });
ga('send', 'pageview');

Comment: Yes, You'll get double pageviews. You should get rid of one of them.